# When a newbie want to install GSL package

Tags: gsl

I'm a newbie in linux package installation so, I will try to be as clear as possible.
I'm trying to install GSL package on my mac (Sierra 10.12.6), in order to install Gflod package after.
So I read the documentation to install it and they said to make ./configure when we are in the good folder, so I did it:

```
loading cache ./config.cache
checking for a BSD compatible install... (cached) /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... (cached) yes
checking for working aclocal... missing
checking for working autoconf... missing
checking for working automake... missing
checking for working autoheader... missing
checking for working makeinfo... found
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... (cached) yes
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin16.7.0
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) works... yes
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) is a cross-compiler... no
checking whether we are using GNU C... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... (cached) gcc -E
checking for a BSD compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... (cached) yes
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin16.7.0
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking for ar... (cached) ar
checking for Cygwin environment... (cached) no
checking for mingw32 environment... (cached) no
checking for ld used by GCC... (cached) /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... (cached) no
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... (cached) -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... (cached) /usr/bin/nm -B
checking how to recognise dependant libraries... (cached) file_magic Mach-O dynamically linked shared library
checking for object suffix... (cached) o
checking for executable suffix... (cached) .dSYM
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output... (cached) failed
checking for dlfcn.h... (cached) yes
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking for strip... (cached) strip
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... (cached)      -fno-common
checking if gcc PIC flag      -fno-common works... (cached) yes
checking if gcc static flag  works... (cached) no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.lo... (cached) yes
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking whether the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... unsupported
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin16.7.0 dyld
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
creating libtool
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) no
checking for size_t... (cached) yes
checking for working const... (cached) yes
checking for inline... (cached) inline
checking for extern inline... (cached) no
checking for main in -lm... (cached) yes
checking for hypot... (cached) yes
checking for expm1... (cached) yes
checking for acosh... (cached) yes
checking for asinh... (cached) yes
checking for atanh... (cached) yes
checking for isinf... (cached) yes
checking for finite... (cached) yes
checking for isnan... (cached) yes
checking for log1p... (cached) yes
checking for vprintf... (cached) yes
checking for memcpy... (cached) yes
checking for memmove... (cached) yes
checking for strdup... (cached) yes
checking for strtol... (cached) yes
checking for strtoul... (cached) yes
checking for clock... (cached) yes
checking for CLOCKS_PER_SEC... (cached) yes
checking for EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE... (cached) yes
checking for IEEE arithmetic interface type... darwin
checking for cpu with extended floating point registers... x86, yes
checking for rounding-control compiler flags... none
checking for IEEE-conformance compiler flags... none
checking whether printf/scanf works with long double... no
updating cache ./config.cache
creating ./config.status
creating gsl-config
creating gsl.pc
creating gsl_version.h
creating gsl.spec
creating gsl/Makefile
creating test/Makefile
creating err/Makefile
creating sys/Makefile
creating utils/Makefile
creating const/Makefile
creating min/Makefile
creating multimin/Makefile
creating ieee-utils/Makefile
creating fft/Makefile
creating specfunc/Makefile
creating dht/Makefile
creating fit/Makefile
creating multifit/Makefile
creating statistics/Makefile
creating sum/Makefile
creating roots/Makefile
creating multiroots/Makefile
creating ntuple/Makefile
creating poly/Makefile
creating qrng/Makefile
creating rng/Makefile
creating randist/Makefile
creating siman/Makefile
creating integration/Makefile
creating interpolation/Makefile
creating doc/Makefile
creating block/Makefile
creating vector/Makefile
creating matrix/Makefile
creating histogram/Makefile
creating monte/Makefile
creating ode-initval/Makefile
creating cblas/Makefile
creating blas/Makefile
creating linalg/Makefile
creating eigen/Makefile
creating permutation/Makefile
creating sort/Makefile
creating complex/Makefile
creating diff/Makefile
creating cheb/Makefile
creating Makefile
creating config.h
config.h is unchanged
```

here, I think there are problems (with the missing autoconf, aclocal, ...)
and after that, when I try to use : make

It doesn't work, and some error messages are displayed:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in gsl
rm -f gsl*.h
HEADERLIST="../gsl*.h ../*/gsl*.h"; \
    for h in $HEADERLIST; do \
      BASENAME=`basename $h`; \
      ln -s $h $BASENAME; \
    done
Making all in utils
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in sys
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in test
/bin/ksh ../libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I..     -g -O2 -c results.c
rm -f .libs/results.lo
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c results.c       -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/results.lo
In file included from results.c:30:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.3.0/include/varargs.h:25:4: error: "Please use <stdarg.h> instead of <varargs.h>"
  #error "Please use <stdarg.h> instead of <varargs.h>"
   ^
results.c:70:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'va_start' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      va_start (ap);
      ^
results.c:73:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'va_end' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      va_end (ap);
      ^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [results.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive-am] Error 2
```

So as I said, I'm a newbie in linux, and I don't really understand where I have to start to solve these problems.
Does-anybody can help me to start my searching?

Thanks a lot

nico

Comment: *I'm a newbie in linux* No you're not, you're a newbie on Mac OS X.  There are at least two widely used package management systems (Homebrew and MacPorts) which make software installation on a Mac as easy as, well as something very easy indeed.

Comment: Oh thanks, it's worked perfectly :)